# solve in passing parameter to jquery plugin file

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have live filter mike merritt plugin and I passing parameter to it in my inline javascript like this:

```
 $("ul#course-group-list").LiveFilter('basic');
```

but it have  JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'LiveFilter'
jquery.livefilter plugin is:

```
(function (a) {
    a.fn.liveFilter = function (d) {
        var c = a(this);
        var g;
        if (a(this).is("ul")) {
            g = "li"
        } else {
            if (a(this).is("ol")) {
                g = "li"
            } else {
                if (a(this).is("table")) {
                    g = "tbody tr"
                }
            }
        }
        var e;
        var b;
        var f;
        a("input.filter").keyup(function () {
            f = a(this).val();
            e = a(c).find(g + ':not(:Contains("' + f + '"))');
            b = a(c).find(g + ':Contains("' + f + '")');
            if (d == "basic") {
                e.hide();
                b.show()
            } else {
                if (d == "slide") {
                    e.slideUp(500);
                    b.slideDown(500)
                } else {
                    if (d == "fade") {
                        e.fadeOut(400);
                        b.fadeIn(400)
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = function (j, k, h) {
            return jQuery(j).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(h[3].toLowerCase()) >= 0
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```